# How to add a document field to new user registration? Classima WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

I need to include a CPF (Brazilian document) field in the registration of new users, but I can't find where to do this. Can you help me ? Thank you all.
I am using Wordpress Classima theme.

I tried looking in the theme's own settings, before making changes to the code.

Comment: https://wpuserregistration.com/ - Try a plugin